# Which test to use to see if tumor weight increases at different stages?

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I have 60 cancer patients. I have checked their staging and the weight of their tumour in gram. One variable is cancer staging - Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3 and Stage 4 (in increasing order). Another variable is Tumour weight - a continuous variable. I want to check as stage increases from Stage 1 to 4, whether tumour weight also increases. Could you please suggest which test should I use?

Comment: Have you seen the [UCLA test decision tree](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Cuzick's trend test](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3992076). This is available as the function "nptrend" in Stata, but I couldn't find an official version in R. A user-contributed version of the test in R is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-December/299074.html).

Comment: Is that a within patients test? It's not clear if these are repeated measures.

Comment: @gung I don't believe [nptrend](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnptrend.pdf#page=3) requires panel data. You just need the groups to be ordered.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider ordinal logistic regression with stage as your dependent variable and weight as an independent variable.

heres a nice tutorial:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm

Comment: Isn't tumor size the outcome?

Comment: logistic regression is fancy like that